# Changing the table row based on a condition

Tags: php, html, mysql

The below code creates a table from mysql on a web page and changes the column background colour based on the gender column value being male or female but I want to extend this to change the row's colour without using javascript/jquery. Please can someone help me with this? :)

```
while($tablev2=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {

echo "<td>".$tablev2['primary_key']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$tablev2['name']."</td>";

if($tablev2['gender']=='male')
    echo "<td style='background-color:powderblue;'>".$tablev2['gender']."</td>";

elseif($tablev2['gender']=='female')
    echo "<td style='background-color:pink;'>".$tablev2['gender']."</td>";
    else echo "<td>".$tablev2['gender']."</td>";

echo "<td><a target = '_blank' href='".$tablev2['link']."'>Click to see their facebook profile</a></td>";

echo "</tr>";
```

}

Comment: Use classes instead of inline styles.

Comment: Where is that <tr> located? is it right before the `while` loop? could you please add this part to get a complete answer?

Comment: funnily enough, I have just been asked to use classes. Is what user3766955 posted a good start to implementing the classes solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply a style on the 'tr' tag depending on the gender value.

```
if($tablev2['gender']=='male'){
    echo '<tr class="bg-male">';
}elseif($tablev2['gender']=='female'){
    echo '<tr class="bg-female">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while($tablev2=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
if($tablev2['gender']=='male')
    echo "<tr style='background-color:powderblue;'>";
elseif($tablev2['gender']=='female')
    echo "<tr style='background-color:pink;'>";
else
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>".$tablev2['primary_key']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$tablev2['name']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$tablev2['gender']."</td>";

    echo "<td><a target = '_blank' href='".$tablev2['link']."'>Click to see their facebook profile</a></td>";

    echo "</tr>";}
```

use background color to TR tag instead of TD tag.
otherwise you have to apply for all TD and it's a bad practice.

Comment: @LeoK : If it really works then please vote up my answer and accept it.
thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow says I need 15 reputation before I can upvote. Otherwise, I would @Parag Soni